# PostgreSQL: Multiple Row Result Using WHILE LOOP

Tags: postgresql, while-loop

I have data as seen below.
[image]

Those data show the fuel tank level on each timestamp, ftakhir is ga.ts's fuel tank level and ftawal is gb.ts's fuel tank level. As you can see gb.ts and ga.ts have a gap between them. I want to know the value of fuel tank level for each timestamp being recorded between ga.ts and gb.ts.

I use WHILE LOOP

```
do $$
declare
   t timestamp := '2020-11-30 13:53:10.596645';
    s timestamp := '2020-11-30 14:04:10.797056';
    id varchar := '05b92dc749ed3a09b35273cac3f3d68aabfcf737';
begin
    while t <= s loop
      PERFORM g.time FROM gpsapi g
       WHERE g.idalat = id AND g.time >= t AND g.time <= t + '1 minute 10 seconds'::INTERVAL;
      t := t + '1 minutes 10 seconds'::INTERVAL;
   end loop;
end$$;
```

Using While Loop, I want it to give multiple result of timestamp between ga.ts and gb.ts, then I need to calculate the traveled distance between the known timestamp.

How to make it as a function so it can give multiple rows of result? Because I am a bit confused how to use the select then while-loop in postgresql

Comment: plpgsql functions are described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql.html). Also take a look at [generate_series(start,stop,step interval)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html).